# Multiple insert POST requests optimization

Tags: json, .net, api, rest

I have this method in my API that takes a POST request with a JSON and save.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("tests/send")]
public class TestAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Test>> Post([FromServices] ApplicationContext context, [FromBody] Test model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Set<Test>().Add(model);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return model;
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

And i have a situation where this method will receive thousands of requests per second.
To avoid calling save changes a lot of times, my idea is to store these objects somewhere and save all at once every 1000 records or something like that (i dont If thats the most correct way).
Is this possible or have any better solution?